# SuppressionFilter in checkstyle.xml read by Codacy?

Tags: checkstyle, codacy

Are [SuppressionFilters](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_filters.html#SuppressionFilter) in checkstyle.xml are followed by [Codacy](https://www.codacy.com)?

```
<module name="SuppressionFilter">
        <property name="file" value="checkstyle-suppressions.xml"/>
</module>
```

So I want to make sure that if the rules specified in the checkstyle-suppressions.xml are also read by Codacy or not?

Please see: https://github.com/openmrs/openmrs-core/blob/master/checkstyle.xml#L45-L47